# Use an ASP.NET or ActiveX component in Java Spring with Tomcat

Tags: asp.net, jsp, tomcat, activex

I would like to ask if I can use the ASP.NET or ActiveX version of [Text Control](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/) in a .jsp web page supported by Java Spring and a Tomcat webserver.
I'm aware of the sw EZ JCom, but I can't afford it. Is there something cheaper?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX is a client side technology, so if your users don't mind installing an ActiveX control, then yes. How the ActiveX control communicates back to the server would depend on the specific ActiveX control.

ASP.NET is a different language, framework, runtime, etc. There are certain cases where you can mix jsp and ASP.NET, such as iframes, and ASP.NET pages that live in the same folder as your .jsp pages, but you won't be able to put jsp tags and ASP.NET tags on the same page and expect things to work.

Comment: Thank you Matthew,I don't know anything about ActiveX or ASP.NET, I'm a Java programmer who is facing for the first time web development. Could you please write something more about the activex control? How could I use in my web app? Maybe if you can take a look at the TextControl activex you can help me with something specific to this case rather than pure theory. Thank you!